# adapt SMALL(,INDEX(FREQUENCY..) to VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm trying to find the minimum non-zero value. I found the following example on the web and tried to adapt it to VBA with no avail.

```
=SMALL((A1,C1,E1),INDEX(FREQUENCY((A1,C1,E1),0),1)+1)
```

Here is my adaption:

```
myarr = Array(A, B, C)
.Range(Cells(D, 1), Cells(WorksheetFunction.Small(myarr,WorksheetFunction.Index(WorksheetFunction.Frequency(myarr, 0), 1) + 1),1)).EntireRow.Delete
```

where A, B, C, D are four integers.

In the debug window, the SMALL function returned "out of context" and as soon as this line of code was executed, the compiler exit the sub as if an "Exit Sub" command was executed.

My guess is FREQUENCY function is not working. How to make it work?

For only three values, it's easy to use a non-function solution such as nested IFs but I'm interested in how to make the functions work as I might need it in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not entirely sure what you are doing but you can do MIN IF inside of Evaluate with an array

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetMinGreaterThanZero()
    Dim arr()
    arr = Array(0, 4, 2, 1)
    Debug.Print Evaluate("=MIN(IF({" & Join(arr, ";") & "}>0,{" & Join(arr, ";") & "}))")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several options here - the simplest option, *if* you have Office 365, is to use the [`MINIFS`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MINIFS-function-6ca1ddaa-079b-4e74-80cc-72eef32e6599) function, like so: `WorksheetFunction.MinIf(myarr, myarr, "<>0")`

But, since you haven't tagged the question as [office365](/questions/tagged/office365), I will use a different option:

```
Private Function MinPositive(Values As Variant) As Variant
    MinPositive = CVErr(xlErrValue)
    On Error GoTo FuncErr
    Dim TempVal As Double, Pointer As Long
    If IsArray(Values) Then
        TempVal = WorksheetFunction.Max(Values) 'High bound
        If TempVal <= 0 Then Exit Function 'No values greater than 0
        For Pointer = LBound(Values) To UBound(Values)
            If CDbl(Values(Pointer)) > 0 And CDbl(Values(Pointer)) < TempVal Then
                TempVal = CDbl(Values(Pointer)) 'Swap for lower number
            End If
        Next Pointer
    End If
    MinPositive = TempVal 'Output the Min value greater than 0
FuncErr:
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't use Office 365. I use Excel 2010.